# Python flask API POST request - JSON data after key

Tags: python, flask, request

I'm very new to development, I'm writing a Python Flask app which is executing a POST request to log a new ticket on a system, I just need someone to verify how I structure this request as I'm really not sure.

The documentation says, for example:

```
curl api/v3/requests 
      -X POST 
      -H "Accept: application/vnd.manageengine.sdp.v3+json" 
      -H "Authorization: Zoho-Oauthtoken 1000.7xxx98976ab0xxxxxx19901e7551be57.bxxxx921ed64c04f79622bebcfxxxxxx" 
      -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" 
      -d input_data= '{
  "request": {
    "subject": "Need an External Monitor",
    "resolution": {
      "add_to_linked_requests": false,
      "content": "The following is the resolution to the above request"
    }
}
```

It's expecting `input_data` key, followed by the JSON array of info to submit.

The documentation is ([here](https://www.manageengine.com/products/service-desk/sdpod-v3-api/SDPOD-V3-API.html#add-request))

My code:

```
 @app.route("/log", methods=["GET"])
def log():
    """Fetching a protected resource using an OAuth 2 token.
    """
    servicedesk = OAuth2Session(client_id, token=session['oauth_token'])

    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer " + token, "Accept": "application/vnd.manageengine.sdp.v3+json", "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}

    data = {
  "request": {
    "subject": "New Incident",
    "mode": {
      "name": "E-Mail",
    },
    "group": {
      "name": "Incident"
    },
    "requester": {
      "name": "Sarah Curtis Test"
    },
    "status": {
      "name": "Open",
    },
    "template": {
      "name": "Report an Incident"
    },
    "request_type": {
      "name": "Incident",
    },
    "description": "This is a test. please ignore",
    "category": {
      "name": "Incident"
    }
  }
}

 requests.post('https://sdpondemand.manageengine.eu/api/v3/requests?input_data=', data=data, headers=headers)
```

I don't have access to logs on the server to see what it is receiving either as it's a cloud service (unless there's a way to echo back the original raw POST request?)

The ticket isn't being logged when I try and do so via my app. It does work through Postman app to test the API request, when I add the JSON above into the `x-www-form-urlencoded` section on the body tab and put `input_data` into the key.

I need to know how to structure the POST request in my code. Any help appreciated! Thanks

Comment: can you try `data=json.dumps(data)` ?

Comment: Thanks, just given that a go, it hasn't worked unfortunately. Would I be right thinking that using data=data should be sending it in the required format i.e. x-www-form-urlencoded (rather than json)?

Comment: Can you share the headers ? [edit] and add them

Comment: @azro sure I've just edited the post

Comment: if you make a post request you don't need `?input_data=` can you try using `requests.post('https://sdpondemand.manageengine.eu/api/v3/requests', data=data, headers=headers)`

Comment: @charchit Ive managed to get the request response to show in the browser now (still learning!). It's expecting the input_data parameter though still, do I need to add this into my data {} instead? 

The error I'm getting is: {
  "response_status": {
    "messages": [
      {
        "field": "input_data", 
        "message": "Value not present for input_data", 
        "status_code": 4001, 
        "type": "failed"
      }
    ], 
    "status": "failed", 
    "status_code": 4000
  }
}

Comment: @sc-leeds try this. remove `input_data=` from the url and send `data = {"input_data":json.dumps(data)}`

Comment: can you try `json=data` or `data=json.dumps(data)`

Comment: You need to pass string to data like `data='{ "requests" : {} .....'` it will work with data = data

Comment: I was able to get this working by using the following -  input_data = ''' { "request": {
                "subject": "'''+subject+'''",
                "mode": {
                    "name": "E-Mail",
                }''' and then specifying this in the post request : full_url = url + '?input_data='+input_data
    servicedesk.post(full_url, headers=headers).json()